# supporting privacy and private transactions in IOTA?

Tags: transaction, iota-network, privacy

Has IOTA foundation planned a system of private transactions (whatever the solution considered "zero proof" or other approaches) to support better the privacy ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The IOTA Development Roadmap (March 2017) mentioned [Private Transactions research](https://blog.iota.org/74741f37ed01#bc83), through coin mixing first and then through more extensive technologies such as zero knowledge proofs.

There was a paper about this topic released on October 2017: [Improving the Anonymity of the IOTA Cryptocurrency](https://laurencetennant.com/papers/anonymity-iota.pdf).

An IOTA Mixer was released into the testnet 1 month later: [IOTA Mixer v1 Released](https://medium.com/iota-ucl/91f3d39735c1).

There has been no noteworthy information regarding this topic since the release of IOTA Mixer v1. In this blog post, [What’s Next: Current IOTA R&D Projects](https://blog.iota.org/eeb8cc03adb5) (June 2018), Private Transaction was not mentioned. From what I can tell, Private Transaction research is currently not a priority for the IOTA Foundation.